# C# save class type as preprocessor

Tags: c#, design-patterns, preprocessor-directive

Is in C# possible to save class type as preprocessor directive like in C/C++?

I have multiple services with a lot of shared code. Main difference is in calling correct `DbSet` & using correct class.

From following code to:

```
public class TaxService
{
    readonly DatabaseContext db;

    public TaxService(DatabaseContext database)
    {
        db = database;
    }

    public async Task<string> DeleteAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (await db.Taxes.FindAsync(id) is Tax tax)
        {
            string title = tax.Name;

            db.Taxes.Remove(tax);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return title;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async Task<List<Tax>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await db.Taxes.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

To e.g:

```
public class TaxService<T> where T : Tax
{
    readonly DatabaseContext db;

    DbSet<Tax> dbSet => db.Tax;

    public TaxService(DatabaseContext database)
    {
        db = database;
    }

    public async Task<string> DeleteAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (await dbSet.FindAsync(id) is T tax)
        {
            string title = tax.Name;

            dbSet.Remove(tax);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return title;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await dbSet.AsNoTracking().OfType<T>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Ofc there is issue in design above. When I try to call `TaxService` I have to pass `Tax` class via generic type => `TaxService<Tax>`

Also in method `GetAllAsync` I have to use `OfType` method to avoid compiler errors. Its not possible to return `List<Tax>` as `List<T>`

Any suggestions to design pattern? Thanks

EDIT (answer to M. B.):

```
public class TaxService : TaxService<Tax>
{
    public TaxService(DatabaseContext database) : base(database)
    {
    }
}

public class TaxService<T> where T : Tax
```

Comment: Repository pattern, combined with "Unit of Work" would fix it.

Comment: @MortenBork thanks for idea. I looked into it and it would work for me if every class (T) had same property (Name) for DeleteAsync method. Sometimes its Title, sometimes its Name.. and I would like to avoid using reflection

Comment: Hi. Please have a look at the example I provided as an answer...
By adding the "expression" as a predicate, you can define in the controller, what to delete by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a base controller like this once.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataAccessLayer.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        public virtual TEntity Get<TContext>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, TContext context) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            var item = context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
            return item;
        }

        public List<TEntity> GetList<TContext>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, TContext context) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            var item = context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList();
            return item;
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetListQueryable<TContext>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, TContext context) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            var item = context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
            return item;
        }

        public List<TEntity> GetAll<TContext>(TContext context) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            var item = context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
            return item;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllEnumerable<TContext>(TContext context) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            IEnumerable<TEntity> item = context.Set<TEntity>();
            return item;
        }


        public virtual TEntity Update<TContext>(TEntity input, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, TContext context) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            if (input == null)
                return null;

            var existing = context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

            if (existing != null) context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(input);

            return existing;
        }


        public virtual TEntity Insert<TContext>(TEntity input, TContext context) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            context.Set<TEntity>().Add(input);

            return input;
        }

    }
}
```

you use it by creating a controller like this:

```
public class TaxcController : BaseController<Tax>
    {
    }
```

and then just creating an instance. This way, you have a controller or repo, to create your overloads, or unique methods in, when something "off" has to be done.

```
public void dostuff()
{
    TaxController taxController = new TaxController();
    taxController.Insert(item, context);

}
```

This very useful when working with a database, that has been built by a drunk programmer in a hurry, because everything that follows the same pattern, can be used, and everything that doesn't can still be used via a controller, the controller just becomes responsible for "screwing around" with whatever exceptions there exist in the database.

This is just a PoC, you don't have to do it precisely as this. Just to get your nogging running.

Comment: Looks good. However I thought of something like #define T Tax like in C++. after reserach on google its not possible in C# :/

Comment: Well, you can add a condition on the where, that you only accept "Tax" class as a T, or that all T must be of class Tax. 

Like : 

public class TaxController<T> where T : Tax
    {}

Comment: I edited my first post. You gave me an idea. Thanks.